# Troubles to change Dropdow list on web application (HTML) with VBA

Tags: html, vba, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get a VBA code to change a drop down list on a webpage. I adapt the code below whitch I already use with success to pass login and password to a webpage, but I am getting trouble with my "adaptation":

```
Option Explicit

Sub Logar_CanalDireto()

Dim ie As Object
Dim ObjElement As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://canaldireto/Claro/CLAR041/default.aspx"

    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    .document.all.Item("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ClaimsLogonSelector").Value = "Windows"

End With

End Sub
```

And here is the HTML code:

```html
Selecione as credenciais que você deseja usar para efetuar logon neste site do SharePoint:
<br />
<br />
<select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ClaimsLogonSelector"   onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ClaimsLogonSelector\',\'\')',   0)" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ClaimsLogonSelector">
<option selected="selected" value="none"></option>
<option value="Windows">Autentica&#231;&#227;o do Windows</option>
<option value="Forms">Autentica&#231;&#227;o de Formul&#225;rios</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector to target element:**

You could use a CSS selector to target the option. E.g.

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ClaimsLogonSelector option[value="Windows"]
```

`#` means className. And then " option[value="Windows"]" means containing `tag` option with attribute `value="Windows"`

---

**CSS query on your HTML sample:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the CSS selector with the `.querySelector` method:

```
.document.querySelector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ClaimsLogonSelector option[value='Windows']").Click
```

Note: I have switched the inner double quotation marks with single to avoid having to escape them in a literal string.

---

**[.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:**

The **Document** method querySelector() returns the first **Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, **null** is returned.

Syntax: **element = document.querySelector(selectors);** <== note the **";"** is not used in VBA.